# Android VideoView: video plays, but throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, video

I use a videoview to open a video from a local media server. This works fine, however logcat shows that every time it opens the video, it gives a FileNotFoundException:

```
2019-01-08 13:42:47.434 27583-27583/com.myapp.contentplayer W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://10.0.0.10:3303/videos/55.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.0.10:3303/videos/55.mp4
2019-01-08 13:42:47.436 27583-27583/com.myapp.contentplayer D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException | SecurityException happend : 
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://10.0.0.10:3303/videos/55.mp4
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1402)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1253)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1176)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1182)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1154)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1178)
    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:399)
    at android.widget.VideoView.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:678)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:773)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:153)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1045)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1863)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8072)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

The video plays, I can pause it, resume it, everything works, however the exception worries me.

Here is the code that creates the view. Playing and pausing is done elsewhere, but removing the controls and not even playing the video is enough to cause the error, despite being able to play the video just fine.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(layout.activity_video_fullscreen);

    mWV = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_full);
    mWV.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("video_url")));
```

Anybody know if this can come back to bite me? Or even if it can't, a way of solving the (apparent) problem (other than a try-catch and ignoring it)?

Comment: Is `http://10.0.0.10:3303/videos/55.mp4` a valid URL? Do you have a custom `FileProvider`?

Comment: I do not have a custom FileProvider, but the url is valid. I have a raspberry pi that serves content using nginx. I can also open the video with a browser over the network, or wget it without a problem.